# How to use tablelayout like look in the flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hi Friends how to set the table layout in the flutter I need to design like the below image

[image: please find the below screen]

Comment: Please show what you have tried before asking the question.

Comment: I am trying to search table layout for flutter but I haven't found anything soi had posted a question that anybody knows how to design this type of layout

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you might want https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html, or something custom with Row and Column objects.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question. Table layouts don't scroll. I don't know Flutter, so maybe GridView does not scroll, but thus answer needs more detail

Comment: Any widget can be placed inside a scrolling widget.  So there's really nothing that "doesn't scroll".